# Infinite union of closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

The set $(0,\infty)$ can be expressed as:

(A) $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]$ where each $a_n$ and $b_n$ is a real number.

(B) $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n)$ where each $a_n$ and $b_n$ is a real number.

(C) $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]$ where each $a_n$ and $b_n$ is a rational number.

(D) All of the above.

I understand that an infinite union of closed sets is open, so neither (B) nor (D) should be the right answer. I think the correct answer should be (A), since we can express $(0,\infty)$ as $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{\pi}{n},n\pi]$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 'an infinite union of closed sets is open' this is wrong, and even if it was true, it wouldn't be the case. Answer is d, try arguing why.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write "an infinite union of open sets is closed".

Comment: @Andy Not trying to discourage you, but that statement is also very wrong: In fact, **any union of open sets is also open**.

Comment: Your $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[\frac{\pi}n,n\pi]$ is fine. What happens if you change $[\frac{\pi}n,n\pi]$ to $(\frac{\pi}n,n\pi)$?

Answer (score 3):

A) and B) and C) all work with for example $a_n=\frac1n, b_n=n$. So D) is correct.

„An infinite union of closed sets is open”. Attention: This is very wrong. It should be: “An infinite union of closed sets **can** be open” (such as in A)). However, for example, the union of the closed sets $[0,1/n]$ is closed; and the union of the closed sets $[1/n, 1]$ is neither open nor closed.